# My Tile Stamper isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've tried to create a 'tile stamper' application that allows you to select a tile from the top and then 'stamp' that tile onto the canvas area below. You can basically think of this as a map editor for an HTML5 game.

Everything is working except for the selecting and stamping: http://www.exeneva.com/html5/tileStamper

The JS error console says my event listeners aren't correct, but I am 100% sure they are valid:

```
// Event listeners
theCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);   
theCanvas.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick, false);
```

Here is my mouse movement and mouse click handling code:

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
  // Accounts for the canvas not being at the top left of screen
  mouseX = e.clientX - theCanvas.offsetLeft;
  mouseY = e.clientY - theCanvas.offsetTop;
}

function onMouseClick(e) {
  console.log("click: " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);
  if (mouseY < 128) {
    // Find tile to highlight
    var totalRows = 7; // 8 total rows, but relative zero means we use 7
    var col = Math.floor(mouseX / tileLength);
    var row = Math.floor(mouseY / tileLength);
    var tileId = (row * totalRows) + (col + row);
    highlightTile(tileId, col * tileLength, row * tileLength);
  } else {
    // stamp the selected tile
    var col = Math.floor(mouseX / tileLength);
    var row = Math.floor(mouseY / tileLength);
    context.putImageData(imageData, col * tileLength, row * tileLength);
  }
}
```

Here is the tile highlighting code:

```
function highlightTile(tileId, x, y) {
  // redraw tilesheet and highlight selected tile
  context.fillStyle = "#aaaaaa";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 128);
  drawTileSheet();

  imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, 32, 32);
  // set alpha to 128
  for (j = 3; j < imageData.data.length; j += 4) {
    imageData.data[j] = 128;
  }

  // draw red line around selected tile
  var startX = Math.floor(tileId % 8) * 32;
  var startY = Math.floor(tileId / 8) * 32;
  context.strokeStyle = "red";
  context.strokeRect(startX, startY, 32, 32);
}
```

Can someone help me figure out why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this line:

```
var theCanvas = $("#canvasOne");
```

`theCanvas` is jquery wrapper, not a pure DOM Element.So it does not have `addEventListener` method.
You could try like this:

```
theCanvas[0].addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);   
theCanvas[0].addEventListener("click", onMouseClick, false);
```

Comment: @YangPulse That's because you are calling `context.putImageData` function with invalid parameters. Check the parameters you are passing.

Comment: I'm not sure how they're NaN. I've defined tileLength = 32 earlier in the code.

Comment: `theCanvas.offsetLeft` in onMouseMove should be `theCanvas[0].offsetLeft` etc. - or simply do a `theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasOne');` instead of creating an unnecessary jQuery object.

Comment: @Niko Okay I've removed the unnecessary jQuery object, but now I'm getting 'undefined' when I click.

Comment: @YangPulse As in Engineer's answer, it's "mousemove" and not "mouseMove"! You definitely need to work on your debugging skills ;)

Comment: @Niko That fixed it! Haha, I totally didn't catch that. Sometimes I mix up camel case and code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
theCanvas.click(onMouseClick);
theCanvas.mousemove(onMouseMove);
```

According to Engineer's answer, you are using jQuery.

PS: You are still working on your tank project? Nice.

Comment: `theCanvas` is a jQuery function, and if `onMouseClick` exists, then it should work.